# How to replicate functionalities of a class in an interface in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I am a Software engineering student and we are having a module named distributed computing. They are using .NET for the tutorials, in one of those tutorials they had asked us to create an interface called BusinessServerInterface that replicates all the functionalities of the data tier and thereafter create a class called BusinessServer that for each function creates a ChannelFactory  and call the required functions in the data tier. I'm confused with how to implement this, Can someone please help me out?
I have included all the classes in the data tier and the DataServerInterface below:

```
//Database class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace DC_tutorial_1
{
    public class DatabaseClass
    {
        //creating a singleton object for the database
        public static DatabaseClass Instance { get; } = new DatabaseClass();
        static DatabaseClass() { }

        List<DataStruct> dataStruct = new List<DataStruct>();
        
        public DatabaseClass()
        {

            var generator = new DataGen();

            for (int i = 0; i < generator.GetNoOfAccts(); i++)
            {
                //doubt
                var temp = new DataStruct();
                generator.GetNextAccount(out temp.pin, out temp.acctNo, out temp.firstName, out temp.lastName, out temp.balance);
                dataStruct.Add(temp);
            }
        }

        public uint GetAcctNoByIndex(int index)
        {
            return dataStruct[index].acctNo;
        }

        public uint GetPINByIndex(int index)
        {
            return dataStruct[index].pin;
        }

        public string GetFirstNameByIndex(int index)
        {
            return dataStruct[index].firstName;
        }

        public string GetLastNameByIndex(int index)
        {
            return dataStruct[index].lastName;
        }

        /*
        public BitmapImage GetPicByIndex(int index)
        {
            return dataStruct[index].picture;
        }*/

        public int GetBalanceByIndex(int index)
        {
            return dataStruct[index].balance;
        }

        public int GetNumRecords()
        {
            return dataStruct.Count;
        }

    }
}

//Data generator class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace DC_tutorial_1
{
    public class DataGen
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        string [] firstName = { "Robert", "Jack", "John", "Jane", "Michael", "William", "David", "Stefan", "Nelson", "Richard", "Charlie", "Mary", "Linda", "Susan", "Jessica", "Kathleen", "Ann" };

        string [] lastName = { "Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Jones", "Davis", "Miller", "Wilson", "Moore", "Taylor", "Anderson", "Thomas", "Jackson", "Citizen", "Doe" };

       
        private string GetFirstName()
        {
            return firstName[random.Next(firstName.Length)];  
        }

        private string GetLastName()
        {
            return lastName[random.Next(lastName.Length)];
        }

        

        private uint GetPIN()
        {
            return (uint)random.Next(1111, 9999);
        }

        private uint GetAcctNo()
        {
            return (uint)random.Next(111111111, 999999999);
        }

        private int GetBalance()
        {
            return random.Next(0, 10000);
        }

        public void GetNextAccount(out uint pin, out uint acctNo, out string firstName, out string lastName, out int balance)
        {
            pin = GetPIN();
            acctNo = GetAcctNo();
            firstName = GetFirstName();
            lastName = GetLastName();
            balance = GetBalance();
            
        }

        public int GetNoOfAccts()
        {
            return random.Next(10000, 99999);
        }

    }
}


//DataStruct class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace DC_tutorial_1
{
    internal class DataStruct
    {
        public uint acctNo;
        public uint pin;
        public int balance;
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        

        public DataStruct()
        {
            acctNo = 0;
            pin = 0;
            balance = 0;
            firstName = "";
            lastName = "";
           

        }
    }
}

//DataServerInterface

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Server
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface DataServerInterface
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int GetNumEntries();

        [OperationContract]
        void GetValuesForEntry(int index, out uint acctNo, out uint pin, out int bal, out string fName, out string lName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the `[visual-studio]` tag is only for questions relating to the Visual Studio application. I've removed it for you.

Comment: Now you need to create a class `BusinessServer` which *implements* `DataServerInterface` (also note that the interface technically violates C# naming guidelines which states that "DO prefix interface names with the letter I, to indicate that the type is an interface." [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces))

Comment: Okay, but what should be included in the Business Server interface then?

Comment: You should include every method definition you need, as you'll be using it instead of the concrete implementation

Comment: Interfaces might be confusing, but there are a lot of good documentation around which will explain in depth how to use/work with them. Let me try to explain it as easy as I can. Please see an interface as a contract for a class. Whenever the class implements this interface, you'll basically tell that class that, the methods defined in this interface (contact), have to be defined. What the logic is behind this method depends. Please see [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) for more details.